# How to set common pagination for two loop in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a page which has two post loops with different post types, i need a common pagination for them is that possible?

The code i am using now is:

FOR POST TYPE 1

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$post_type = 'custom post type 1';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $post_type,
  "$tax" => $slug,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 15,
   'paged' => $paged,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
  'orderby'=>'title',
  'order'=>'ASC'
);
query_posts($args); ?>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div><?php the_title(); ?></div>
   <?php endwhile; ?>
   <!-- pagination -->
   <?php kriesi_pagination(); ?>
```

FOR POST TYPE 2

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$post_type = 'custom post type 2';
$args=array(
  'post_type' => $post_type,
  "$tax" => $slug,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 15,
   'paged' => $paged,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
  'orderby'=>'title',
  'order'=>'ASC'
);
query_posts($args); ?>
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div><?php the_title(); ?></div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <!-- pagination -->
  <?php kriesi_pagination(); ?>
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't merge the two loops? Can you post more of your code so we can see the structure?

Answer (score 0):

If your loops are next to each other it might be easiest if you simply merge them into one and pass an array for the post_type:

```
$post_type = array( 'custom post type 1', 'custom post type 2');

$args=array(
  'post_type' => $post_type,
  "$tax" => $slug,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => 30,
   'paged' => $paged,
  'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
  'orderby'=>'title',
  'order'=>'ASC'
);
```

Comment: But i need the post_types 1 to appear in the top and the post_type 2 to appear at the bottom. if i merge i dont think its possible, and also i need to sort them in alphabetical order at the time of display

Comment: You can use filters to order your posts by type and title. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11276753/2126792 for an example.